# TableLayout inside ScrollView

Tags: android

I want to make something like

[image]
In Eclipse in UI tool all looks OK, but when i test app on Emulator or device
bottom buttons appears on top of the fields.
I want:
 buttons - at the bottom ;
 first and second field ;
 third field must take all free space between 1 and 2 fields and buttons.
If I use only RelativeLayout -> all UI is OK(But there is problem with Soft-keyboard)
But when I use RelativeLayout inside ScrollView the above mentioned problem is being appeared.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

......

Maybe someone faced with some problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use following code in xml

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout >
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" >
            <EditText />
            <EditText />
            <EditText />
        </LinearLayout> 

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button />
                <Button />
        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

it may solve your problem

Comment: But how can I make second linearlayout to be at the bottom of the screen and third EditText of the first linearlayout to fill all free space between EditText1 +EditText2 and buttons ?

Comment: I noticed that android:fillViewport="true" works for me in UI eclipse tool but not works on devices.